# How to find QuickBooks Sales Receipt by DocNumber?

Tags: quickbooks

I am using Intuit QuickBooks desktop version, I wanted to find Sales Receipt in QuickBooks by Doc Number property of Sales Receipt, Is there any way to find. 
Currently I have only one way like fetching all Sales Receipts and find into that but as it take time to fetch large amount of data.
Is there any way to find QuickBooks Sales Receipt by DocNumber?

Thanks,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs that Intuit provides via IPP do not support querying by DocNumber. See the "Filtering" section of the docs for sales receipts for fields you can filter by:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/salesreceipt